# Get the last element of a docker image path using Go templates

Tags: docker, shell, go, go-templates

I would like to generate a synthetic `docker ps` table but my docker image paths are very long. The solution I am trying to do is to display only the last part of the image name:

This is what I have:

```
docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}\\t{{.Image}}\\t{{.Status}}\\t{{.Command}}"

NAMES                    IMAGE                                                           STATUS          COMMAND
a_container              a_local_image                                                   Up 36 minutes   "python…"
another_container        registry.example.com/group/subgroup/project/my_image:latest     Up 38 minutes   "go…"
```

I would like:

```
docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}\\t{{ <magic .Image> }}\\t{{.Status}}\\t{{.Command}}"

NAMES                    IMAGE               STATUS          COMMAND
a_container              a_local_image       Up 36 minutes   "python…"
another_container        my_image:latest     Up 38 minutes   "go…"
```

so basically, get what is after the last `/`, like `basename` does.

This is what I tried:

```
# No fixed length
docker ps --format "table {{ slice .Image  0 10}}"

# No last index available
docker ps --format 'table {{ (split "/" .Image) }}'
```

Any help or workaround is appreciated.

p.s.: since I use docker cli, I don't think I can define custom functions to use in the template expression.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good way to get the last element of a template array. Even though you can use `index` and `len` built-ins, you can't use arithmetic to get `len - 1`.

This is a template-only trick:

```
{{ $image := "" }}{{ range split .Image "/" }}{{ $image = . }}{{ end }}{{ $image }}
```

Basically it does the following:

- declare a var `$image`
- [`split`](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/#split) the `.Image` on `/`
- iterate over the array string and just assign to `$image`
- at the end of the range, `$image` will hold the value of the last element
- print `$image`

Full command (with enclosing apex `'` so you don't have to escape quotes):

```sh
docker ps --format 'table {{.Names}}\t{{ $image := "" }}{{ range split .Image "/" }}{{ $image = . }}{{ end }}{{ $image }}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Command}}'
```

Comment: In terms of content it is good, but could I have the table header (line with the columns names) by chance ?

Comment: @Benjam to me it looks like a bug in the docker formatting, given that the `.Names` header is printed correctly, but others aren't — the docs assume usage of plain templating, so this trick to print the last element was probably not envisioned, and the code that prints the table header doesn't handle it properly

Answer (score 0):

You may could use next workaround, I put it in a shell file just because it's too long, but you are ok to call it directly in shell.

**test.sh**

```
paste <(docker ps --format 'table {{.ID}}') \
    <(docker ps --format 'table {{.Image}}' | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}') \
    <(docker ps --format 'table {{.Command}} {{.CreatedAt}} {{.Status}} {{.Ports}} {{.Names}}')
```

**Explain:**

- `docker ps --format 'table {{.ID}}'` get the `ID` column of `docker ps`
- `docker ps --format 'table {{.Image}}' | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')`, frist get the `Image` column, then use `awk` to split `/`, get the last sub column as you required.
- the left is used to get remained columns as you needed of `docker ps`
- Finally, use `paste` command to combine the output of above command.

Comment: Thank you but it appears the colomns are no longer aligned to their content